# SVN Server running on Windows Vista in a Home Network, Accessing from Mac OS X

Tags: windows, svn, macos, networking

I have SVN running on my main windows development box on my home network. I access the server from various development laptops depending on what I'm doing. I also do this with a Mac OS X development laptop but I apparently have to use the IP Address of the SVN Server.

This is causing problems because the IP address of the SVN server changes. On my windows machines, I can access SVN  via the servers name.

Is it possible for me to do something like this from my Mac? Or perhaps some configuration so I can "configure" my mac to to name an IP Address? (Perhaps the hosts file?)

Thank you all!

Regards,
Frank

**Update**: I access my SVN repository on my Mac with [ZigVersion](http://zigversion.com/). I use a URL like the following: http://Frank@192.168.1.7/svn/RepositoryName/

**Update 2**: While Chris gave a good answer (that I understand), I was hoping for something a little more elegant. If you think this is the best method, please chime in by voting. I'm looking for other ideas but also community opinion on how this might be accomplished.

Also, If it'd be possible to Post this on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/), please let me know how.

Comment: Good idea but I don't have Beta access. The home page is asking for a beta access password right now.

Comment: alt.sysadmin.repository is the password

Comment: That password doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Maybe add the belongs-on-serverfault tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have my router set up to give my server the same IP so that I don't run into this issue.  If I were you, I would just set up a static IP either through Windows or through your router.

Comment: I may do this, but I suppose I was looking for a more elegant way of accomplishing this... I'd really like to be able to access the "server" by a name as opposed to IP address

Comment: The only other option is to install software on the apple laptop that will associate NetBIOS names with IP addresses.  I've seen Linux systems do it, but there is usually a domain controller or Samba server somewhere on the network that plays a part in making it work.  Just go with the router config, or leave the server on 24/7 so it never requests a new IP address.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your windows machine is using a windows-specific method of broadcasting its NetBIOS name. The OS X system is trying to lookup the DNS name. Your DNS system should be fixed to allow the DHCP server to assign hostnames.

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you are trying to say. I understand most of the acronyms or at least recognize them however I don't know how I'd make the DNS System be fixed to allow the DHCP server to assign host names....